# How to change Xmpp Ip addess to domain name

Tags: xmpp, tigase

I'm using the XMPP tigase 7.1.3 version. Connecting with IP address like xx.xx.xx.xx:5222 it is working without issue. But I need to change this IP address to a domain. I used **xmpp.mydomain.com** and that domain added to the xmpp **etc/init.properties**  it is like this

```
--admins=admin@xmpp.mydomain.com,10005@xmpp.mydomain.com
--virt-hosts=xmpp.mydomain.com
```

when I change it to a domain name My APP is not connected to the XMPP and  always requests getting timeout. There are no errors in the tigase server log files.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would recommend upgrading to the [latest stable version: 8.2.1](https://github.com/tigase/tigase-server/releases/tag/tigase-server-8.2.1).

As for the issue at hand - you should be aware that there are two addressing in XMPP:

1. `hostname` - name of the single machine (or the IP address)
2. `domain` or `virtual hostname` (i.e. `VHost`) which is the domain that your deployment (group of servers) can server.

In your case you should have never used IP address in the configuration file for domain/VHost - the IP identifies the machines which should be transparent for your users. However, if you have used IP and want to switch to domain this is the (rough) steps that you should take:

1. change the IP to domain (xmpp.mydomain.com) in init.properties
2. change all usernames in your database (table `tig_users`) and update the `<username>@<IP>` to `<username>@xmpp.mydomain.com` (please keep in mind that you should also update sha1 column.
3. configure DNS entry, including SRV records, to point to the IP of the machine